# FreeBSD make error - File 5.19 supports only version 12 magic files. /usr/share/misc/magic.mgc is version 8?

Tags: freebsd, perl, make, proftpd, freebsd-ports

I'm having trouble reinstalling ProFTPD on a FreeBSD 10.1 setup. The server is newly upgraded from 10.0 to 10.1. When I start the make install clean process, these warnings first shows on screen.

```
===>  proftpd-1.3.5_4 depends on shared library: libpcre.so
/usr/share/misc/magic, 93: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `, %ld pages'
...
/usr/share/misc/magic, 15118: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `Volume %ld,'
/usr/share/misc/magic, 15609: Warning: Current entry does not yet have a description for adding a MIME type
file: File 5.19 supports only version 12 magic files. `/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc' is   version 8
[: =: unexpected operator
- not found
```

And after i while, the make process stops with this error:

```
/bin/ln -s libpcre.so.1 /usr/ports/devel/pcre/work/stage/usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.3
====> Compressing man pages (compress-man)
===>  Installing for pcre-8.35_2
===>  Checking if pcre already installed
===>  pcre-8.35_2 is already installed
You may wish to ``make deinstall'' and install this port again
by ``make reinstall'' to upgrade it properly.
If you really wish to overwrite the old port of pcre
without deleting it first, set the variable "FORCE_PKG_REGISTER"
in your environment or the "make install" command line.

*** Error code 1

Stop.
make[3]: stopped in /usr/ports/devel/pcre
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make[2]: stopped in /usr/ports/devel/pcre
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make[1]: stopped in /usr/ports/ftp/proftpd
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/ports/ftp/proftpd
```

Seems that the file /usr/share/misc/magic.mgc is of a wrong version? This might happens when I was upgrading from 10.0-RELEASE-p12 to 10.1-RELESE-p1?

If i run make install clean of the ProFTP port, and disable support for pcre, the process and install is successful. But I believe that something is still broken?

My programming skills are limited, and also this level of error. Please let me know if you have any ideas,

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependency checking in the ports Makefiles uses `file(1)` to check that a file is a shared library.

It seems like your magic database which is what `file` uses to determine file type is broken. You can recreate it as follows, assuming you have the FreeBSD source code installed.

First, create the total database in text format;

```
cat /usr/src/contrib/file/magic/Header \
/usr/src/contrib/file/magic/Localstuff \
/usr/src/contrib/file/magic/Magdir/* >magic
```

Then compile it;

```
file -C magic
```

Now install both in their default location. This needs to be done as root;

```
install -m 644 magic magic.mgc /usr/share/misc/
```